# Why does the value of 11 correspond to white in this grayscale image(matplotlib)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a numpy array. The top half of the numpy array is filled with 11s, and the bottom is filled with zeroes. When I plot this array using matplotlib, I expected the entire screen to be some shade of black. However, when I plotted it, it turns out that the top half is white(the same shade as if the value was 240) and only the bottom half is black. I have no idea why this is happening, and would greatly appreciate any help.

Here is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
print("ehllow")
zeroes = np.zeros((10,10))
zeroes = zeroes + 240
zeroes = np.concatenate((zeroes,np.zeros((10,10))),axis = 0)
print(zeroes)
plt.imshow(zeroes,cmap = "gray")
plt.show()
```

And the output image is
[image: As]

As is shown in the picture, the grayscale value when I hover over the white portion is still 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

matplotlib is for plotting data, not images directly.  `imshow` normalized from vmin to vmax, and if you dont' specify those, it calculates them based on the data.  If you'd like to normalize so that 0 is black and 255 is white, then

```py
plt.imshow(zeroes, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
```

https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html